# Each address that not exists, redirect to one page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have some links in footer of a `MasterPage`. ***Home, About, Terms, Contact*** and so on. The **Terms** link has `navigateUrl` as : `"~/en-us/Terms"` and for **Contact** link: `"~/en-us/Community/Contact"`.
In `global.asax`, my route table is as follow:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "en-us/Terms", "~/EN_US/Terms.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("", "en-us/Community/Contact", "~/EN_US/Community/Contact.aspx");
```

My problem is: I don't add **Community/Contact.aspx** in my solution yet, so when I click on `Contact` link, I expect to receive `The resource cannot be found` error, but it redirects to `Terms` page. Worse than that, every addresses that not exists, also do the same. For example, when I try `"localhost:1384/en-us/someWords/anotherWords"` (Exactly the same), it redirects to *Terms* page.
I delete cookies, delete browser history, delete ASPTemplate Files, shutdown VS, restart Windows, Clear solution, rebuild it and any thing else. and the problem remains
I use VS.2012, asp.net 4.

After `Contact` link was clicked, in browser address bar, I see `localhost:1384/en-us/Community/Contact`, but the content of page is exactly like **Term** page and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not giving the routes names, the first one becomes the default route.  Thus defaulting to Terms.

Comment: I give name to each route and problem exists yet.